# Angular JS and Node routing/wiring - data only showing after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, url-routing

I'm using Node and Anugular, and I have created a RESTful api from my application, and created an angular resource to use this. I'm confused as to how the Angular ui-router directive reconciles with the Node Routing system on the server.

At the moment I have set up my routes/states in ui-router like this:

```
$stateProvier
.state('admin', {
            url:'/admin',
            templateUrl:'views/admin.html', 
            controller: 'adminController'
        });
```

And this loads into the ui-view on my homepage, when I navigate to this url from a link on the loaded page.

**HOWEVER**, when I manually type in localhost/admin I get the route from Node, rather than the state render through angular.

Now I'd like to Angular to handle all the navigation on my app, and my resource to get the information, even if the address is typed manually into the navigation bar.

I've created a route in Node is for index, which contains my index.html page from angular, which effectively contains the whole app angular code, including all the routing.

My question is, how can I get angular redirect if I manually type the url into the address bar, and still have the data from the $resource.

I'm directing my resource to '/admin' - could this be the problem?

Does this mean that I need to add the contents of /routes/appointments' into the base node file (server.js), and then remove the route? If so then how do i direct my resource to the correct REST api?

app structure

public
  -angular app
  -app.js //for angular
routes
  index.js
  appointments.js
models
views
 - index.ejs
server.js //node server file

here is my code exerpts
server.js

```
//standard routing code
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var appointments = require('./routes/appointments');

var app = express();
//configuring Express
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/', appointments);
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// ./routes/index.js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Homepage' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

routes/appointments.js - this is the basis of my RESTFUL api

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Todo = require('../models/Appointments.js');

/* GET /todos listing. */
router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
  Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(todos);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via the Accept header. If the request only accepts JSON then let the request go through to your API. If the request accepts HTML then always serve up your index page. Then once the index page loads angular's router will take care of the rest.

```
// Angular config - default Accept header for all ajax requests
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

// Middleware in Node to "intercept" non JSON requests
// Place this after express.static middleware but before your route definitions.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // keep in mind this applies to all requests, so 404s will need to be handled by your angular app since any url will serve up the index page
    if(req.header('Accept') !== 'application/json') {
        console.log('serving the index page');
        req.url = '/'; // force the url to serve the index route.
    }

    next();

});
```

One more thing to note about this approach is that obviously you won't be able to see/debug your JSON data by hitting the URL directly anymore. There are several useful tools like Advanced REST Client or POSTman which actually give you better control and more options for things like that. Just make sure you set the Accept header in one of those tools and you'll be able to see the JSON response.

Comment: Hey Ryan - thanks for this - but this leads to an unexpected error - i'm using ui-router - and now if I link to any page passing the id into the stateParam, I'm still redirected as this isn't an application/json type header - how can I use this method but still pass stateParams to ui-router?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the URL you are trying to access? I'm not sure if I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The actual URL is `localhost#!/admin`, try that. Angular hides the hashbang #!

Angular's URL routing is an "illusion" in that way. It only works on the client-side and only when your Angular app is loaded, which is on the main `/` route.

A solution could be to conditionally redirect from `localhost/admin` to `localhost#!/admin`, i.e. redirecting to your Angular app and passing *it* the `#!/admin` path. The condition could be a check for whether or not JSON was requested.

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.header('Accept') !== 'application/json')
    return res.redirect('/#!/admin');
  Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(todos);
  });
});
```

You'll also need to configure Angular such that when it requests '/admin' json data from the server, it should only accept json (by setting the request header), which is how the the server will distinguish it from the regular '/admin' request. For that, if you're using [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you would do `$http.get('/admin', {'Accept':'application/json'})`

Comment: hi laggingreflex - thanks for this - but now I'm not able to get the data from the backend to render out on the page - I've tried using Postman to check and there is no response at all coming back

Comment: Most probably what you'll also need is to configure Angular such that when it requests '/admin' json data from the server, it should only accept json (by setting the request header), which is how the the server would be able to distinguish it from the regular '/admin' request. For that, if you're using [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you would do `$http.get('/admin', {'Accept':'application/json'})`

Comment: That's great - how could I do that using $resource